# Postgres materialized views or CREATE TABLE AS if not updating incrementally?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

If I don't plan to implement incremental updates for materialized views in Postgres, are there any advantages to using them over `CREATE TABLE AS`?  From what I have read, when you refresh a materialized view, that view locks and is not readable.  Since it's unavailable, it seems to have the same affect as dropping and recreating a table at the same rate you run refresh on a materialized view.

Comment: I think you are right. The only advantage I see is that the "refresh" statement is much shorter and you don't need to re-state the whole query for that. Might be an advantage depending on how you manage your DDL scripts

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you should really add that as an answer -- because it basically *is* the answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As of PostgreSQL 9.3.2 you also cannot use materialized view data as basis of UPDATE query.
So if you need to use this view as a basis of some updates then you are better of using regular tables.